# How does the ADAM optimizer output a specific value for v_t in keras?

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow, keras, adam

I want to look at the results of each iteration of the ADAM algorithm that computes v_t, so I added the following code to the Adam class in the keras\optimizers.py file:

```
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
```

**I want to get every numeric value in this shape, similar to the form of a matrix.** **But the output below is not what I expected:**

`v_t: Tensor("training/Adam/add_2:0", shape=(8, 512), dtype=float32)`

```
v_t: Tensor("training/Adam/add_5:0", shape=(128, 512), dtype=float32)
```

This line of code is part of the Adam class itself, and the next line adds its own:

```
v_t = (self.beta_2 * v) + (1. - self.beta_2) * K.square(g)
print('v_t:',v_t)# This is my added code
```

I made the following attempts but would report the error as follows:
**InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape [-1,1,8] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: lstm_1_input = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1,8], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]**

This is my model:

`model = Sequential()`

`model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))`

`model.add(Dense(1))`

```
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam',metrics=['mae'])
```

I just want to output every value in this shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your backend is Tensorflow you can use [tf.Print()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) to print the value of a tensor.

Comment: I tried the method you provided. The code is as follows: `a = tf.Print(v_t,[v_t,v_t.shape,'any thing i want'],message='Debug message:',summarize=100)``print('a:',a)`The result is still the same.`a: Tensor("training/Adam/Print:0", shape=(8, 512), dtype=float32)` I want every number in the shape.

Comment: I used ipython, not compatible with the output of the desired value. Change to the command line can be, thank you for the answer.